# change color of self.navigationItem.prompt

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to change color of navigationItem.prompt??

```
self.navigationItem.prompt = @"What would you like to order today?";
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to achieve the same thing within my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look like it. There are probably various hacks you can do by fiddling with the navigation bar's view hierarchy...